# PHP form processing issues

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have been trying numerous ways to get the email addresses entered into the form here: http://contest.realfamilytrips.com saved to a file of some sort. I have had no luck. Now I am trying to email myself with each entry and not having much luck with that either.

I put together a bit of PHP code (after hours of research. I'm pretty new to this end of things) that was supposed to email me each time a user inputs their email address into the form, but it isn't working.

This is a single-page landing page so there's not a ton of code. I'd like to share the index.html and my php script, as well as the stylesheet and functions.js files. If anyone can tell me how to get these email addresses either saved or emailed or something I would be very grateful.

INDEX.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>iPad Air Giveaway</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="css/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/video-js.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" >
   <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="animated_favicon1.gif" >

</head>
        <body class="type-3">
        <p></p>
<!-- Shell -->
    <div class="shell"><!-- Sidebar --> <aside id="sidebar">
        <div class="item"><img src="css/images/ipadgraphic.png" alt="win an ipad air" /></div>
        <p style="text-align: left;">Enter sweepstakes to win a brand new iPad Air. Unsubscribe<br /> anytime. <a href="http://realfamilytrips.com/real-family-trips-great-family-itinerary-contest-terms-conditions/">Click here for official terms and conditions</a></p>
        </aside> <!-- END Sidebar --> <!-- Content --><section id="content"><!-- Logo -->
        <h1 id="logo"><a href="http://realfamilytrips.com" title="home">Real Family Trips</a></h1>
    <div>
        <h2>Win an iPad Air</h2>
        <h2 class="pull-up">For The Best Family Itinerary</h2>
        <p style="text-align: left;" class="intro-text"><em>Hey there World Traveler!</em></p>
        <p style="text-align: left;" class="intro-text"><em>Want to win an <span class="largetext">iPad Air</span> in a contest for the best family itinerary? Start by answering the question below. You can also share this with others, so more families can learn how to travel with their kids for the best experience!<span size="-1"><a href="http://realfamilytrips.com/real-family-trips-great-family-itinerary-contest-helpful-hints/" style="text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #095DF7;"> more details</a></span></em></p>
<!-- Step 1 -->
    <div class="steps step-1">
        <h2 style="font-size: 26px;">STEP 1: Answer this question</h2>
            <form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="select-holder"><label>Who is giving away a new 7.5" retina display iPad Air?</label>
            <div class="select-wrap"><select name=""> <option selected="selected" value="Select Your Answer">Select Your Answer</option> <option value="LeadBrite, Duh!">RealFamilyTrips, hello...</option> <option value="Lady Gaga">My next door neighbor</option> <option value="Santa Claus">Santa Claus</option> </select></div>
            </div>
        <input value="Submit Answer&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" class="submit-button" type="submit" /></form>
                <div class="contest-ends">
                <p><span>Contest Ends</span></p>
                <p>January 31st, 2014 2:00 pm E.S.T.</p>
                </div>
    </div>
<!-- END Step 1 --> 
<!-- Step 2 -->
    <div class="steps step-2">
        <h2 style="font-size: 26px;">STEP 2: Your details</h2>
&nbsp; <form action="signup.php" method="post" name="emailaddy">
                    <input type="text" class="field" value="Enter your email address" title="Enter your email address" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="send" />
                </form>
            <div class="contest-ends">
            <p><span>Contest Ends</span></p>
            <p>January 31st, 2014 2:00 pm E.S.T.</p>
            </div>
    </div>
<!-- END Step 2 --> 
<!-- Step 3 -->
    <div class="steps step-3">
        <h2 style="font-size: 26px;">STEP 3: Submit Itinerary</h2>
        <a href="http://realfamilytrips.com/share-itineraries"> <input value="Go!" class="send" type="submit" /> </a>
            <div class="contest-ends">
            <p><span>Contest Ends</span></p>
            <p>January 31st, 2014 2:00 pm E.S.T.</p>
            </div>
    </div>
<!-- END Step 3 -->
        <p class="inspired">brought to you by <a href="http://realfamilytrips.com">Real Family Trips</a></p>
        </div>
    </section><!-- END Content -->
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!-- END Shell -->
    <p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

SIGNUP.php:

```
<?php

/* Subject and Email variables */

    $emailSubject = 'Real Family Trips Contest';
    $webmaster = lifeleavesscars@gmail.com

/* Gathering Data Variables */

    $emailField = $_POST['emailaddy'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Email address: $email <br>
EOD;

    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail ($webmaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

STYLE.css:

```
@import url('fonts.css');

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0; }

body, html { height: 100%; }

body {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-family: 'SegoeUI', arial, sans-serif;
    color: #314b7b;
    background: #fff url(images/body1.png) repeat-y center 0;
    min-width: 980px;
}

a { color: #0252aa; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
a img { border: 0; }

em { font-style: normal; font-family: 'SegoeUI-Italic'; }
.largetext { font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; }

input, textarea, select { font-size: 18px; font-family: 'SegoeUI', arial, sans-serif; }
textarea { overflow: auto; }
select { background:none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; border: 0;   font-family: 'SegoeUI'; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; width: 367px; -webkit-appearance: menulist; margin: 0 5px 0 4px; }

.cl { display: block; height: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; clear: both; }
.notext { font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; }
.left, .alignleft { float: left; display: inline; }
.right, .alignright { float: right; display: inline; }

h2 { font-family: 'SegoeUI-Bold'; font-size: 30px; line-height: 36px; color: #314b7b; text-align:center; font-weight: normal; }
h2 span { font-size: 36px; display: block; padding-bottom: 2px; }

.shell { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }

#logo { width: 289px; margin: 0 auto; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; padding-bottom: 14px; }
#logo a { display: block; width: 289px; height: 62px; background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat 0 0; text-indent: -4000px;  }

#sidebar { display: inline; float: left; width: 503px;  padding-top: 32px;  }
#sidebar h2 { width: 380px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 30px; }

#content { display: inline; float: right; padding: 27px 13px 0 11px; width: 415px; }
#content h2 { color: #010101; text-shadow: 0 1px #fff; padding-right: 6px; letter-spacing: -1px; }
#content h2.pull-up { position: relative; margin-top: -6px; padding-bottom: 17px; }
#content p.intro-text { width: 372px; margin: 0 auto; text-align:center; padding: 0 0 9px 24px; }
#content p.inspired { font-size: 15px; text-align:center; color: #8f8f8f; text-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #f6f6f6 }
#content p.inspired a { color: #8f8f8f; text-decoration: underline; }
#content p.inspired a:hover { text-decoration: none; }

.steps { padding-bottom: 29px; }
.steps p { font-size: 20px; line-height: 30px; color: #010101; width: auto; text-align:center; }
.steps form label { display: block; padding-bottom: 23px; }

.steps form p a { color: #015978; text-decoration: underline; }
.steps form p a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
.steps form .select-holder { margin-top: 7px; padding: 13px 19px 20px 13px; background: #fff; }
.steps .select-wrap { width: 375px; border: solid 1px #707070; padding: 2px 0 4px 0; margin-left: 1px; }
.steps .submit-button { display: block;  width: 346px; height: 73px; margin: 16px auto 0; background: url(images/submit-button.png) no-repeat 0 0; border: 0; }
.steps .submit-button { font-family: 'SegoeUI-Bold'; font-size: 30px; color: #212121; cursor: pointer; text-shadow: 0 1px #faf562; letter-spacing: -1px; }
.steps .submit-button:hover { background-position: 0 -73px; }
.steps .send { display: block;  width: 346px; height: 73px; margin: 16px auto 0; background: url(images/send.png) no-repeat 0 0; border: 0;}
.steps .send { font-family: 'SegoeUI-Bold'; font-size: 30px; color: #212121; cursor: pointer; text-shadow: 0 1px #faf562; letter-spacing: -1px; }
.steps .send:hover { background-position: 0 -73px; }
.steps .field { margin: 25px 0 17px 6px; padding: 10px 20px 11px; line-height: 28px; width: 366px; box-shadow: inset 3px 5px 3px 3px #f5f5f5; background: #fff; border: solid 1px #d7d7d7; }

.step-2 { display: none; }
.step-3 { display: none; } 

.contest-ends { padding-top: 16px; }
.contest-ends p { font-size: 20px; line-height: 24px; color: #8f8f8f; text-shadow: 0 1px #fff; text-align:center; } 
.contest-ends p span { display: block; line-height: 18px; font-size: 15px; }

body.type-2 { background: #e1e1e1 url(images/body2.png) repeat-x 0 0; }
body.type-2 #wrapper { background: url(images/wrapper.jpg) no-repeat center 0; }
body.type-2 #logo { width: 365px; }
body.type-2 #logo a { width: 365px; height: 62px; background: url(images/logo2.png) no-repeat 0 0; }
body.type-2 .steps p { color: #fff; }
body.type-2 #sidebar h2 { margin-top: 10px; width: auto; color: #2e0035; }
body.type-2 #content p.intro-text { font-family: 'MuseoSlab-500'; font-size: 24px; line-height: 30px; width: auto; padding: 2px 0 16px 0; color: #2e0035; }
body.type-2 .select-holder { margin-left: 2px; }
body.type-2 .select-holder label { padding-bottom: 13px; }
body.type-2 .submit-button { margin-top: 23px; }

body.type-3 { background: #fff url(images/body3.png) repeat-y center 0; }
body.type-3 .shell { width: 874px; }
body.type-3 #logo { padding-bottom: 19px; }
body.type-3 #sidebar { padding-top: 29px; width: 354px; }
body.type-3 #sidebar h2 { padding: 0 0 42px 0; margin-top: 9px; width: 280px; }
body.type-3 #content { width: 495px; }
body.type-3 #content h2.pull-up { padding-bottom: 22px; }
body.type-3 #content p.intro-text { padding: 0 0 27px 10px; width: 433px; }
body.type-3 .steps p { letter-spacing: 1px; }
body.type-3 .select-holder { margin: 16px 30px 0 35px; padding:  13px 19px 20px 18px; }
body.type-3 .submit-button { margin-top: 29px; }
body.type-3 .contest-ends { padding-top: 12px; }
body.type-3 .field { margin: 20px 0 17px 47px; }
body.type-3 #sidebar p { font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; text-align:center; padding-right: 14px; padding-left: 14px; }
body.type-3 #sidebar p a { color: #666; text-decoration: underline; }
body.type-3 #sidebar p a:hover { text-decoration: none; }

#mc_embed_signup{ font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; text-align: center; }
```

FUNCTIONS.js

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('focusin', '.field, textarea', function () {
        if (this.title == this.value) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    }).on('focusout', '.field, textarea', function () {
        if (this.value === '') {
            this.value = this.title;
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.submit-button', function () {
        if ($('select').find('option:selected').index() === 0) {
            alert('Select Your Answer.');
            return false;
        }

        if ($('select').find('option:selected').index() !== 1) {
            alert('Your guess is wrong! Please try again.');
            return false;
        } else {
            $('.step-1').hide();
            $('.step-2').fadeIn(800);
            return false;
        }
    });

    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
        // Check email address
        // if email address ok
            $('.step-2').hide();
            $('.step-3').fadeIn(800);
            e.preventDefault();
        // else 
            // alert
            // e.preventDefault();
        // end if
    });
});
```

Thanks and sorry for all the code. I don't know if it was needed but after so many days of trying I thought perhaps the jquery was messing with the php? Not sure. At this point I have no idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually have the quotes at the start and end of each file?

Comment: For one thing, your signup.php code has a missing semi-colon in `$webmaster = lifeleavesscars@gmail.com` so that alone will throw an error and break your code. Fix that and test it again. EDIT: As [Barmar mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864427/php-form-processing-issues#comment31304078_20864427). Change that line to `$webmaster = "lifeleavesscars@gmail.com";`

Comment: It also has missing quotes around the email address.

Comment: In step 1, why do you have a form that doesn't go anywhere?

Comment: You have a point there @Huey it should go to `<form action="SIGNUP.php" method="post">`

Comment: Thanks, I missed the quotes around the email. They should be double quotes? And luckily we don't need the answer to step 1 because I would have no idea how to store that data either.

Comment: and lsmooth, no I don't. Backticking gone awry.

Comment: You're missing the closing form tag on your first form and I don't think the divs match. Use good code indentation to help spot those kinds of errors. Do you have error reporting turned on? Have you tried an HTML formatter?

Comment: I added the quotes and I have not received an email. I am guessing there is still an error besides this.

Comment: I will check that out, Revent. Thanks. Hopefully you caught it.

Answer (score 0):

Your form markup is incorrect. You're giving the `form` element a `name` attribute, when you should be putting it on the input. Correct markup:

```
<form action="signup.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="field" name="emailaddy" value="Enter your email address" title="Enter your email address" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="send" />
</form>
```

Also, in your PHP file, this line is incorrect: `$webmaster = lifeleavesscars@gmail.com`. You're missing quotes and a semicolon.

If it's still not working, are you getting an email at all, is it just missing the user's email address, or what?

I tried to POST to your PHP file and got a 200 ok response and saw no errors, is error reporting enabled?

```
Request Url: http://contest.realfamilytrips.com/signup.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200
Params: {
    "emailaddy": "test@test.com"
}

Status Code: 200
Date: Wed, 01 Jan 2014 00:43:01 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Content-Length: 24
```

The best way to do this is to save the email addresses to a database.

Comment: single quotes or double quotes for the email address?

Comment: @user252415 It doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm now getting emails with the subject heading correct and the body of the email correct. There's just no email address listed. That's progress, right?

Comment: @user252415 That's good. I just realized you're using `$emailField` to get the email address from the POST array but you're trying to use `$email` in your `$body`. Change the two variables to match and it should work.

Comment: Not sure why but now I'm not getting any emails. I changed each variable to $email. Here's what the php code looks like now http://pastebin.com/q1XmLurz

Comment: @user252415 Weird, I don't see anything immediately wrong with it.